# Does the func bike () at the top has been overriden by another function at the bottom

Tags: javascript, function, binding, this, bind

```
var bike = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
var name = "Ninja";
var obj1 = { name: "Pulsar" };
var obj2 = { name: "Gixxer" };

var originalBikeFun = bike;
bike = function() {
  originalBikeFun.call(obj1);
};

bike();           // "Pulsar"
bike.call(obj2);  // "Pulsar"
```

I need explanation because I cant get it. Does the function at the top (which is bike) get overridden when I assigned originalBikeFun at her. How does that work? (Btw, I copy the examples provided by mdn only) #javascript

Comment: Yes, it does get overwritten. After all, you assign a new function to `bike`.

Comment: `bike = function() {
  originalBikeFun.call(obj1);
};` Yep...

Comment: `bike` is just a reference to a certain value. When you set it to another value, it will no longer point its previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain step by step what in your fragment of code going on:

1. You declare variable `bike` and assign to it **reference** to this function:

```
function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

2. You declare variable `originalBikeFun` and assign **reference** to function mentoined above. At this moment you have two variables `bike` and `originalBikeFun` that points to just one area in memory where your function stored.
3. You assign (**dereferencing**) to `bike` variable this new function:

```
function() {
  originalBikeFun.call(obj1);
}
```

At this moment you have variable `bike` pointed to this function:

```
function() {
  originalBikeFun.call(obj1);
}
```

and variable `originalBikeFun` pointed to previously assigned function:

```
function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

4. When you call to `bike` function these lines of code executes:

```
a) originalBikeFun.call(obj1);
b) console.log(this.name);
```

So the result of this call is "Pulsar".

5. When you call to `bike.call(obj2)` the difference between previous function call is you just pass `obj2` as `this` pointer, but because in function `bike` you have only one call with reassign `this` pointer, so there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks man! So it means that it wont point to the previous one but its her reference?

Comment: It means, that if we talk about objects (literals, functions...) variables always only store reference to these. You can declare one function and more than one variable that just point to this function. So every variable that points to an object serves as a pointer to some area in memory. Every manipulation with reference cause manipulation with object in memory. Dereferencing is when you take variable with assigned object and reassign it to a new object (already declared or instantiated right now).

Comment: :) Hard work and learn JS via documentation. Be aware that above things are just a small part of whole interesting world of JS. I wish you good luck and productive work.